# echo the input data to another page php

Tags: php, forms, submit

I got a problem in show the input data from one page to another page

I try to transfer it when we click the submit button

this is my code which is I try to transfer the data

```
function cart() {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value>0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_'){
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM menu WHERE id=' .mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                    echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ $'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = $'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />' ;
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
    if ($total == 0){
        echo "Your Cart Is Empty";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Total : $".number_format($total, 2).'</p>';


        <p>
        <form action="bill.php" method="post">
        <?php paypal_items(); ?>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        </p>            
    }
}
```

I try to show this line to another page

```
 echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ $'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = $'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />' ;
```

And I just try this code and I got error

bill.php

```
<?php
echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ $'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = $'.number_format($sub, 2);
?>
```

the error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: get_row in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\bill.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\bill.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: get_row in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\bill.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: sub in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\bill.php on line 2
x @ $0.00 = $0.00
```

anyone know how to do it???

I'm just a newbie in this field...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `session_start();` to the first line of your first php file. then add

```
$target_data = $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ $'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = $'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />' ;
$_SESSION['target_data'] = $target_data;
```

before echo. Then in your second php file, again add `session_start();` to the first line and you may echo value like;

```
echo $_SESSION['target_data'];
```

Comment: you're welcome. :) consider upvoting and accepting my answer (click up arrow and tick icon) if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

then if you are using the session, save that string into the session.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to carry some variable from one page to other then use session variables

### first.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable_name'] = $whatever;
```

### second.php

retrieve data like below

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['variable_name']; // return value of $whatever
```

and in your case you post data on **bill.php** so get data on bill.php by POST variable

```
print_r($_POST) // return all data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display value in another page use `$_POST,$_GET` and `$_SESSION` instead of directly use variable name.

Read this for better unserstand: http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save your session variables to allow them to move between pages, you need to call session_write_close() when you are done.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
session_write_close();
?>
```

doing this allows you to access session data outside of the page it was set on.

More information here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php